# How Set Neovim startup directory to Desktop in windows?

Tags: lua, directory, neovim, neovide

I'm using Astro vim distro with neovide. every time I launch neovide / neovim-qt it launches in the directory it's installed on!

OS: windows 10
[Astrovim starting location][1]
[using windows shortcut properties to set start in location][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvXfp.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEl4N.png

is there a way to set startup location in options.lua ?

Comment: yeah, it is possible. Try use `VimEnter` autocmd event and combine with `:cd` command. I think it will achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code in your configuration file, it make use of vim\neovim [autocommands feature](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html):

```lua
local os = require("os")

local path_to_desktop = os.getenv("USERPROFILE") .. "\\Desktop"

local vim_enter_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup("vim_enter_group", { clear = true })

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    {"VimEnter"},
    { pattern = "*", command = "cd " .. path_to_desktop, group = vim_enter_group }
)
```

`nvim_create_autocmd` and `nvim_create_group` are described in neovim docs. Use `:h nvim_create_autocmd`to find out more.